# How to ignore null and empty value when use Neo4jOperations.save() to update properties with Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

spring-data-neo4j : 4.1.2
neo4j:3.0.3

Node :

```
Person {id:1, name:"aa", cover:"1.jpg"}
```

Class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person{
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String cover;
    ...
}
```

New object:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setId(1);
p.setName("bb");
```

then update data:

```
p = neo4jOperations.save(p,0);
```

or:

```
personRepo.save(p,0); // interface extends GraphRepository<Person>
```

result:

```
Person {id:1, name:"bb"}
```

Question: cover property has been deleted，because p.cover is null. Is there a way can ignore null value when update?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not supported in SDN. A null value means that the property is removed from the underlying graph.

You can still write a custom cypher query though (this would defeat the purpose of SDN if this is your major use case)